# How to get all string except the first word in Python

Tags: python, string, split, strip

How do you get rid of the first word of the string? I want to get rid of the number and get the rest as a whole string.

Input text is:

```
1456208278 Hello world start
```

What I wanted for output was:

```
'Hello world start'
```

Here was my approach:

```
if isfile('/directory/text_file'):
    with open('/directory/test_file', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            try:
                first = str((lines[0].strip().split()))
                final = first.split(None, 1)[1].strip("]")
                print final

            except Exception as e:
                print str(e)
```

The output of the code was:

```
'Hello', 'world', 'start'
```

I do not want " ' " for every single string.

Comment: Always provide the language tag so that it'll be easier for people to help you.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am pretty new here. Is there an way for me to edit the question so that I can add some more tags just like you mentioned?

Comment: There is no "edit" button at bottom? Then we can edit it for you. Just tell what tags to add.

Comment: Can you tell us that the que belongs to which language??

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution with the `partition()` method:

```
In [41]: '1456208278 Hello world start'.partition(' ')[2]
Out[41]: 'Hello world start'
```

Comment: This is the actual way to go. I didn't know about the `partition` method, but I prefer your solution to mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you split and then join, you may lose spaces which may be relevant for your application. Just search the first space and slice the string from the next character (I think it is also more efficient).

```
s = '1456208278 Hello world start'
s[s.index(' ') + 1:]
```

### EDIT

Your code is way too complex for the task: first you split the line, getting a list, then you convert **the list** to a string, this means that you will get `'` and `]` in the string. Then you have to split again and clean the stuff. It's overly complex :)

Another approach you could use it to split and join, but as I said earlier, you may lose spaces:

```
s = '1456208278 Hello world start'
t1 = s.split() # ['1456208278', 'Hello', 'world', 'start']
t2 = s[1:] # ['Hello', 'world', 'start']
s2 = ' '.join(t2)
```

or more concisely

```
s2 = ' '.join(s.split()[1:])
```

This approach could be better if you want to use comma to separate the tokens, e.g.

```
s3 = ', '.join(s.split()[1:])
```

will produce

```
s3 = 'Hello, world, start'
```

Comment: Your answer is really awesome. Very straight-forward. Thank you for your help! I will try that tomorrow when I get back tomorrow! :) God bless you.

Comment: The answer's correct. The default approach he provided is the most intuitive though - it doesn't manipulate different data structures back and forth, but the fact that he provided multiple solutions to reveal different thinking can be valuable to beginners and whatnot. Anyways, without doubt, give him/her the well-deserved points!